# My terminal's indentation is not working properly

Tags: vim, terminal, vi, indentation

I am mac user. When I'm using Vim in the termianl autoindent does not work at all.
Indentation only works when I tab in manually, through next line.

I already apply autoindent, cindent like that. Here is my .vimrc code. I really need your help.

```
  1 " 환경설정                                                              
  2 syntax on
  3 
  4 set nu
  5 set hi=100
  6 set ru
  7 set mps+=<:>
  8 set backup
  9 syntax enable
 10 colorscheme desert
 11 set history=50
 12 set visualbell
 13 set noerrorbells
 14 set loadplugins
 15 
 16 set encoding=utf-8
 17 set fileencodings=utf-8,cp949,default,latinl
 18 set termencoding=utf-8
 19 set printencoding=utf-8
 20 set printmbcharset=ISO10646
 21 
 22 " Editing
 23 set paste
 24 set tabstop=4
 25 set softtabstop=4
 26 set shiftwidth=4
 27 set showmatch
 28 set autowrite
 29 set autoindent
 30 set cursorline
 31 set showcmd "show commandline
 32 set title "show title
 33 set statusline=\ %<%l:%v\ [%P]%=%a\ %h%m%r\ %F\     " 다중 문서 작업을 >>
    위한 Status 줄
 34 set km=startsel,stopsel "shift키로 선택 영역 만들기 허용
 35 " 영역 상태에서 ctrl+f, b 로 이동하면 영역 해제
 36 

 37 set smartindent
 38 set expandtab
 39 set cindent
 40 set autoindent
 41 set textwidth=80 " if it is over 80 char
 42 set wrap " then it warped next line
 43 set nobackup
 44 set shiftwidth=4 "autoindent at 4 line
 45 set ignorecase " no large-small character difference when it is searched
 46 set laststatus=2
 47 
 48 " window
 49 set ruler   "show cursor position
 50 
 51 " macro
 52 map <F2> :tabnew<CR>
 53 map <F4> :w<CR>
 54 
 55 " c 파일의 경우 Makefile이 없으면 gcc를 불러줌
 56 au BufRead,BufNewFile *.c
 57 \ if !filereadable("Makefile") && !filereadable("makefile") |  
 58 \ set makeprg=gcc\ %\ -o\ %< | 
 59 \ endif 
 60 
 61 " cpp 파일의 경우 Makefile 이 없으면 g++를 불러줌
 62 au BufRead,BufNewFile *.cpp
 63 \ if !filereadable("Makefile") && !filereadable("makefile") |  
 64 \ set makeprg=g++\ %\ -o\ %< | 
 65 \ endif 
 66 
 67 " java 파일의 경우 Makefile 이 없으면 javac를 불러줌
 68 au BufRead,BufNewFile *.java 
 69 \ if !filereadable("Makefile") && !filereadable("makefile") |  
 70 \ set makeprg=javac\ %  |
 71 \ endif
 72 
 73 " 지난번 편집했던 곳으로 Jump
 74 au BufReadPost *
 75 \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
 76 \   exe "normal g`\"" |
 77 \ endif
```

Comment: While this has nothing to do with your problem, you might want to cleanup all the duplicates (`autoindent shiftwidth etc.`) in your vimrc. Also, `smartindent` does nothing useful and should be removed and I'd suggest you add `filetype plugin indent on`. See `:help :filetype`.

Comment: Allright. Thanks romainl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `set paste`. Paste mode will effectively disable indentation.

Comment: @Sogo While you're at it, use [`pastetoggle`](https://github.com/timss/vimconf/blob/master/.vimrc#L386) instead.